# How do I make this python automation code using Pyautogui faster and safer?

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

This is a code that I use to register my courses for semester. I want this code to run fastest as possible so that I can select my preferred courses faster than other students who select them manually, the seats and section of desired classes fill-up fast. My concern is that if my code runs faster and the browser cant keep up with it then it will cause issue. For example I will be running on google chrome browser. And what should I change to make this code faster without risking Thanks in advance.

```
import pyautogui
import time
import webbrowser

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab')

##Subject choose
time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'f')
pyautogui.write('PHY182.1')
pyautogui.press('enter')
pyautogui.press('esc')
pyautogui.hotkey('shift', 'tab')
pyautogui.press('space')
```

Comment: If you're concerned about the program being too fast for the browser, why do you want to make it faster? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I want this code to run fastest as possible so that I can select my preferred courses faster than other students who select them manually, the seats and section of desired classes fill-up fast

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar I while ago, not exactly your case but I believe it would help. If you want it to be as fast as possible while making sure that the browser if keeping up with you, you should make your script recognize that the page you are going to be on has fully loaded, for this I would use selenium, so when the page is fully loaded it does the thing really fast, but not before. I think that if you did it like that it would work.

You have to setup selenium first, it's a bit long so I won't explain here, I'll just give you an example of it being used.

Selenium example:

```
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(url) # goes to url and waits till it's loaded #
    einput = driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId") # find the element you want through it's name #
    einput.send_keys(email) # what you want to write #
    einput.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) # enter #
```

I used this code for a script I made that logged people into google really fast in incognito. But I believe you could adapt it to your case. It's not perfect though because some pages 'never finish loading' but give it a try.